# Javascript Function Call inside dropdown change event Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

```
var TourItinerary = {  
    EXCURSIONS:{

    },
    init:function(){
        console.log('Initializing...');
        this.initializeElements();
    },       
    initializeElements:function(){
        console.log('init elements...');
        $("select[id^='start_city_']").change(function(){
            var day_id = $(this).attr('id').replace("start_city_","");
            getPossibleExcursions(day_id);
        });
    },    
    getPossibleExcursions: function(day_id){
        console.log('Day Id ='+day_id);
    }
};
```

how to call **`getPossibleExcursions(day_id)`** function inside dropdown change event?

It always shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getPossibleExcursions is not defined.

Comment: `var self = this;` at the start of the function, then `self.getPossibleExcursions(day_id);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Devesh now it shows **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Comment: `TourItinerary.getPossibleExcursions` if you only need this to work “statically” ...

Comment: CBore thanks for the replay. But still get the same error. **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Comment: Use self.getPossibleExcursions(day_id);

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign `this` to some variables for future reference. When you define change event, `this` refers the DOM object that you are going to add event, not the actual object. So assign `this` to some variables, say `self` and reuse it in the on change function.

Now you can use both `self` for referring the object and `this` for the DOM object

```js
var TourItinerary = {  
    EXCURSIONS:{

    },
    init:function(){
        console.log('Initializing...');
        this.initializeElements();
    },       
    initializeElements:function(){
        console.log('init elements...');
        var self = this;
        $("select[id^='start_city_']").change(function(){
            var day_id = $(this).attr('id').replace("start_city_","");
            self.getPossibleExcursions(day_id);
            console.log("value = " + $(this).val());
        });
    },
    getPossibleExcursions: function(day_id){
        console.log('Day Id ='+day_id);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    TourItinerary.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="start_city_123">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
   <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
```